# Is this a proper customized synchronizer?

Tags: java, multithreading

I had a strong need for a synchronizer similar to a CountDownLatch, but the starting number for the countdown is unknown. To add context, if I'm going through a buffered recordset (say from a text file or a query) and kicking off a runnable for each record, but I don't know how many records there will be... I need a synchronizer that signals when the iteration is complete and all runnables are complete.

This is the synchronizer I came up with... a BufferedLatch. A method is called in the iteration loop for each record incrementing the recordSetSize. At the end of each runnable kicked off for each record, the processedRecordSetSize is incremented. When the iteration through all records is complete (but runnables may still be in queue), the setDownloadComplete() method is called letting the BufferedLatch know the recordSetSize is now fixed. The await() method waits for the iterationComplete variable to be true (recordsetSize is now fixed) and recordsetSize == processedRecordSetSize;

Is this an optimal implementation of this synchronizer? Is there more concurrent opportunity that synchronization is holding back? Although testing seems to work fine, are there any gotcha's I'm overlooking?

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public final class BufferedLatch {
/** A customized synchronizer built for concurrent iteration processes where the number of objects to be iterated is unknown
 *  and a runnable will be kicked off for each object, and the await() method will wait for all runnables to be complete
 */
    private final AtomicInteger recordsetSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final AtomicInteger processedRecordsetSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private volatile boolean iterationComplete = false;

    public int incrementRecordsetSize() throws Exception { 
        if (iterationComplete) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot increase recordsize after download is flagged complete!");
        }
        else {
            return recordsetSize.incrementAndGet();
        }

    }
    public void incrementProcessedRecordSize() { 
        synchronized(this) { 
            processedRecordsetSize.incrementAndGet();
            if (iterationComplete) {
                 if (processedRecordsetSize.get() == recordsetSize.get()) { 
                     this.notifyAll();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    public void setDownloadComplete() { 
        synchronized(this) { 
            iterationComplete = true;
        }
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException { 
        while (! (iterationComplete && (processedRecordsetSize.get() == recordsetSize.get()))) {
            synchronized(this) { 
                while (! (iterationComplete && (processedRecordsetSize.get() == recordsetSize.get()))) {
                    this.wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE-- NEW CODE

```
public final class BufferedLatch {
/** A customized synchronizer built for concurrent iteration processes where the number of objects to be iterated is unknown
 *  and a runnable will be kicked off for each object, and the await() method will wait for all runnables to be complete
 */
private int recordCount = 0;
private int processedRecordCount = 0;
private boolean iterationComplete = false;

public synchronized void incrementRecordCount() throws Exception { 
    if (iterationComplete) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot increase recordCount after download is flagged complete!");
    }
    else {
        recordCount++;
    }
}
public synchronized void incrementProcessedRecordCount() { 
    processedRecordCount++;
    if (iterationComplete && recordCount == processedRecordCount) { 
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
public synchronized void setIterationComplete() { 
    iterationComplete = true;
    if (iterationComplete && recordCount == processedRecordCount) { 
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}

public synchronized void await() throws InterruptedException { 
    while (! (iterationComplete && (recordCount == processedRecordCount))) {
        this.wait();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "customized synchronizer"? You use `synchronized` everywhere, I don't see what's custom...

Comment: `synchronized` is implemented with locks -- as soon as you use it, you have killed your concurrency completely. The point of using atomic values, etc is to avoid `synchronized`. `synchronized` is not your friend.

Comment: I don't see why you are synchronizing atomic wrapper

Comment: I'm looking for a counterpart for a CountDownLatch, Semaphore, etc... that does the behavior I described above.

Comment: Well, no, it is not a proper "custom synchronizer"

Comment: @Jarrod The other question covers some similar issues but it's not really a duplicate in my opinion. This question covers different issues such as synchronizing across multiple fields, latching behavior, DCL, and wait/notify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. I think conceptually you're onto something here, as it looks like your application needs something more than just a `CountDownLatch`. However, the implementation seems to have several problems.

First, I note that it looks odd to mix atomics/volatiles AND ordinary object monitor locks (`synchronized`). While there may be proper uses that mix these different constructs, mixing in this case I believe will lead to errors.

Consider `incrementRecordsetSize()` which first checks `iterationComplete` and only if it's false does it increment `recordsetSize`. The `iterationComplete` variable is volatile so updates from other threads will be visible. However, the fact that no locking is done here allows TOCTOU race conditions (time-of-check vs time-of-use). The rule seems to be, `recordsetSize` must not be incremented if `iterationComplete` is true. Suppose thread T1 comes along and finds `iterationComplete` to be false, so it decides to increment `recordsetSize`. Before it does so, another thread T2 comes along and sets `iterationComplete` to be true. This would allow T1 to do the increment improperly. Worse, before it does so, suppose another thread T3 came along and called `incrementProcessedRecordSize()`. It would increment `processedRecordsetSize` and then find `iterationComplete` true. It further might find that `processedRecordsetSize` equals `recordsetSize` and then notify all waiters, who then proceed as if the processing is complete. But it's not, as T1 then proceeds to increment `recordsetSize` and presumably continues with its processing.

The problem here is that this object's state consists of the fusion of three independent pieces of state -- two int counters and a boolean -- and all three must be read and written atomically. If certain bits of logic attempt to take advantage of individual volatile or atomic properties, it introduces the possibility of race conditions such as the one I described.

I'd suggest rewriting this as a plain object with two plain ints and a boolean (not atomic, not volatile) and just lock around everything. This should certainly clear up the logic and make things easier to understand.

In `incrementProcessedRecordSize` I note that the condition essentially duplicates the condition in the `await` method. A simplifying convention is for all updates to notify and have the condition evaluated only by the waiters. This may result in some unnecessary wakeups. If this is a problem, you might consider minimizing the number of notifies, but you need to think about maintainability. If you're not careful, the wait/notify conditions will become spread across the code and will be very hard to reason about. Alternatively, you could refactor the condition into a method and call it from the different places that do waiting and notification.

It looks like `await()` does a complicated form of double-checked locking. Instead of testing a volatile boolean outside the lock, it tests several separate pieces of information both outside and inside the lock. This seems susceptible to TOCTOU problems (as above) but it **might** be safe if you can prove the state really latches, that is, that once it becomes true it never returns to false. I'd have to stare at the code for a long time before I'd be able to convince myself it's correct.

On the other hand, what does this buy you? It seems to optimize away just the taking of the lock. If you have a zillion threads that are going to come by after processing is complete, it might be worth it, but it doesn't seem like it. I'd just remove the outer while loop and check the variables within a `synchronized` block.

Finally, having an object that represents counters and a boolean may very well be sensible for what you're doing, but other things you've said (in the question and in comments) are that some threads are generating a workload (e.g. reading lines from a file) and other threads are retiring that workload. This implies that there is some **other** data structure like a queue that contains this workload, and you have a producer-consumer problem here. That other structure has to be thread-safe, of course, since multiple threads are interacting over it. But the counters and boolean in **this** structure need to be updated in lockstep with the updates to the workload structure, otherwise there could be race conditions between checking and updating these separate objects.

It seems to me you could replace the counters in this object with the queue and just put simple locks around everything. The producers would append to the queue until they're done, at which time they set `iterationComplete` to true which prevents more work from being added. The consumers pull from the queue until `iterationComplete` is true and the queue is empty, at which point they're done. If they find the queue empty but `iterationComplete` is false, they know to block while awaiting further work.

I'd say to stick with simple locking and avoid volatiles/atomics until you get the basics correct. If there are bottlenecks in that code, then apply optimizations selectively while preserving the same invariants.

Comment: That's a pretty impressive analysis! I felt I was overcomplicating things a lot hence why I posted this.  I've only been doing concurrency development for a few months and am probably redundantly synchronizing out of fear for race conditions. I will work on this in the next day or two and post when I have a simplified this class design.

Comment: Yeah I did end up typing a lot, didn't I? Glad I posted this before the question was closed! (I've lost answers b/c the question was closed while I was still editing.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and seeing the value and specific nature in what I was asking! I'll post followup later.

Comment: Okay I updated the code to your suggestions. Thank you! I tested it and it seems to work great, and it makes much more sense. I tried to identify any race conditions and I think they only would occur if methods were called in illogical places in iteration loop.